# In Batch, how to copy files within a user specified range

Tags: batch-file

I have a scenario where I need to copy files from five subdirectories to the directory where the batch file exists.  These files are sequential in name in each subdirectory.  For example:

FolderA:
A001.txt
A002.txt
A003.txt
A004.txt

FolderB
B001.txt
B002.txt
B003.txt
B004.txt

FolderC
C001.txt
C002.txt
C003.txt
C004.txt

and so on.  What I want to be able to do is have a user input where I am able to copy the files from each directory that end in 003 and 004 to a new directory. I have more of the batch that does some data scrubbing from there with the copied files.  My problem is getting the files copied based on my number range.

I am able to add a user input to allow me to select all file that end in 003 and copy them, but then I have to run it again to get all files that end in 004.  I have close to 25,000 files to search through, and I have completed data mining some.  I need to copy them in from a range.

Here is what I have that works to allow me to input and copy a single file set

```
set fname=
set /P "FileNumber=Please enter File Number: "
if defined FileNumber for /R "\client\A001\M0093" %%I in ("*%FileNumber%*.xml") do (copy /Y "%%I" "\Extraction\Files\"
    set "fname=%%~I"
)
if defined fname (
cls
@echo off
copy "Files\*.txt" Data.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can specify a range and use `for /l` to process them. I.e `set "begin=%1"` then `set "end=%2"` then run `for /l %%i in (%begin%,1,%end%) do echo 00%%i` this example can be launched  by running the script from `cmd` as `scriptname.cmd 3 4`

Comment: How can I use this and still have a user input to select the range.  For example when my code asks me to enter file number, I want to be able to copy the files with 01075 - 01163. I'm not sure I am following, and I am not highly versed in batch programming.  What I have is what I have been able to figure out through google searches.

Comment: Please straighten out the requirements. You start out with 3-digit numbers, zero-filled. Then your comment mentions 5-digit numbers. The difference is significant. You start with `.txt` files, then switch to `.xml` - and what's the concatenate-all-the-text-files about?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting from my mobile, so none of this has been tested:

```
@echo off
set /P "begin=beginning number"
set /P "end=Ending number"
Pushd "client\A001\M0093"
For /l %%i in (%begin%,1,%end%) do for /R %%b in ("*%%i*.xml") do copy /Y "%%~b" "%~dp0"
```

Also, this assumes the files are copied to the path where the batch-file is located, as you have mentioned.